# Vertical outline chord diagrams with the songs package

Tags: formatting, positioning, songs

I would like to better outline my chord diagrams with the songs latex package if this is possible. My output now is this:

[image: not_outlines_chords]

As you can see the F# (the name of the chord) is not aligned with C#m7, G#m has too many notes before the barre and the diagram of Dmaj7 is not aligned with the rest.

What I would like is something like:

[image: good_outline]

This is from ultimate-guitar.com, but as you can see all chord diagrams and chord names are outlined.

Is it possible to do this with the Songs package?

Below is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[chorded, onesongcolumn]{songs}
\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Some Song}[by={Some Guy}]

\gtab{C#m7}{X42100:042100}
\gtab{F#}{2:(244322):034200}
\gtab{G#m}{(477444):034000}
\gtab{E}{022100:023100}
\gtab{Dmaj7}{XX(222)}
\gtab{C#}{X43(121):X43020}

\beginverse
\[Am]Alas my love, you\[G]do me wrong
\[F]to cast me off so \[E7]discourteously,
\[Am]for I have loved you \[G]for so long,
\[F]delighting \[E7]in your \[Am]company.
\endverse

\beginchorus
\[C]Greensleeves was \[G]all my joy,
\[F]Greensleeves was\[E7]my delight,
\[C]Greensleeves was my \[G]heart of gold,
and \[F]who but my \[E7]lady \[Am]Greensleeves.
\endchorus

\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I solved the issue with G#m having too many notes before the barre by editing the chord into:

```
\gtab{G#m}{4:(133111):034000}
```

But the alignment issue of the chordname of F# diagram of Dmaj7 still exists.

EDIT 2:
While Sandy G's solution is a good way to do it, I solved it using `\patchcmd` from the `\usepackage{etoolbox}` package. Now it looks like this:
[image]

The relevant code for this is:

```
% make chord diagrams same length
\minfrets=5

% raise chord name when no open/muted strings
\patchcmd{\SB@topempty}
  {\relax}% search
  %{{\phantom{\framebox(1,5.15){}}}}% replace
  {{\phantom{$\times$}}}% replace
  {}{}

% raise chord diagram when no fingering is present TODO still one 0 must be present for this to work!
\patchcmd{\SB@finger}
{\SB@topempty}
{{\phantom{$\times$}}}
{}{}
```

What this does is insert a hidden x (with `\phantom`) above and below the chord diagram.
This must be added in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the chord names vertically aligned, you can enclose any chord name in a `\raisebox` command. Depending on the font you may have to adjust this some. But then `\gtab` won't center the chord name. To correct that, add a `\quad` space before the chord name. It doesn't matter how wide the chord name is.

```
\gtab{\raisebox{5.15pt}{\quad F#}}{2fr:(133211):034200}
```

[image]

To simplify this, I created the command `\all` that takes the chord name as an argument:

```
\newcommand{\all}[1]{\raisebox{5.15pt}{\quad #1}}
```

I don't have a great solution for the bottom alignment issue, except to use a `'` character. It's the most innocuous character I could find that `songs` will accept for a finger.

I also changed the barre chords to be more consistent with the notation from ultimate-guitar.

Here is the code to produce the above image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[chorded, onesongcolumn]{songs}

\newcommand{\all}[1]{\raisebox{5.15pt}{\quad #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}

\minfrets=5
\gtab{C#m7}{X42100:042100}
\gtab{\all{F#}}{2fr:(133211):034200}
\gtab{\all{G#m}}{4fr:(133111):034000}
\gtab{E}{022100:023100}
\gtab{Dmaj7}{XX0(222):{00000'}}
\gtab{C#}{X43(121):X43020}

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to automate the inclusion of the `\raisebox` like this? Maybe with `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`?

Comment: @jansen, it's probably easier if you just use `\newcommand`. I edited my answer. Does that do what you want?

Comment: This is a good solution and a quick way to make the chords better, thank you! But I ended up hacking the desired functionality in with \patchcmd after reading the `songs` source code, see my edit for the details

Comment: @jansen, I like your way better. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `\minfrets=5` to make all the tabs the same height.